# how to divide large text content to be displayed in more than one page in tcpdf php?

Tags: php, tcpdf

I have large text content as a product description and one page can't contain it.
How can I divide this description to fit more than one page dynamically according to its length?
Is there a built in method on tcpdf class that does this approach?
This is my code :

```
$tab_top = 88 + $height_incoterms;

$pdf->SetFont('','', $default_font_size - 1);
$pdf->writeHTMLCell(190, 3, $this->posxdesc-1, $tab_top, $notetoshow, 1, 1);

$nexY = $pdf->GetY();
$height_note=$nexY-$tab_top;

$pdf->SetDrawColor(192,192,192);
$pdf->Rect($this->marge_gauche, $tab_top, $this->page_largeur-$this->marge_gauche-$this->marge_droite, $height_note);

$tab_height = $tab_height - $height_note;

$tab_top = $nexY+20; //tab for the next item
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to split your text into chunks sized by your maxlength, and display each chunk on a new line.